# Home network advice

Tags: networking, vpn

I currently have a modem/router from the ISP which is connected to a Netgear R7000 running xwrt-vortex. I would like to setup a VPN on my home network to allow me to remotely connect to my LAN.

Ideally I would like to have all this on the R7000 since this allows me more control as well as configuring DDNS etc.

However it's informing me of this:

> The wireless router currently uses a private WAN IP address

When trying to setup OpenVPN.

Any advice would be appreciated or pointers to some home networking 101.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have plugged in a router (Netgear) behind another router (ISP Modem) that are both doing NAT.

This is a bad design for multiple reasons, one of which you just ran in to.

You need to put your ISP Modem in to “bridge” mode and disable all routing/firewall functionality. This will allow your Netgear to obtain a public IP address and disable the double-NAT issue you have right now.

You might be able to do this from the ISP modem’s Web config page. Or, you might need to call your ISP and request they do this for you.

Comment: This should be enough to get me going! I'll try to see if i can put the ISP Modem into bridge mode.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/255206/how-use-your-router-and-isps-modemrouter-combo-in-tandem/ - exactly this ;)

Comment: So I found out the ISP modem has PPPoE passthrough - could this be leveraged to help?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it. But that might mean you need to configure the PPPoE connection on your Netgear. I’m not for sure. Either way you are on the right track.